How to create a cluster wide function in kusto query language
I have a cluster with 3 database one each for Dev,PPE and prod, I want to setup configuration so that it will be easy to perform operation on these database by using their environment.
I have created a config database which holds the
.create table EnvironmentConfig (Environment:string, DatabaseName:string)

.ingest inline into table EnvironmentConfig <|
Environment | DatabaseName
------------|-------------
Dev         | DevDB
PreProd     | PreProdDB
Prod        | ProdDB


Now I want to create a cluster-wide function which will return the database name when called from individual databases,
The cluster-wide function:
.create-or-alter function with (skipvalidation = "true") 
GetCurrentEnvironmentDatabase(env:string)
   {
      let db = toscalar(
          ConfigDB.EnvironmentConfig
          | where Environment == env
          | project DatabaseName
      );
      db
   }

and the function to get database name in each cluster:
.create-or-alter function GetDatabaseName(env:string)
{
    cluster("YourCluster").GetCurrentEnvironmentDatabase(env)
}

Now, How to create this cluster-wide function : GetCurrentEnvironmentDatabase ?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

What is cluster wide function

Have you seen this article

It looks like this is not possible

Yes. I posted this question to Kusto team, will update if I get any answer.
